# RegOpenCurrentUser handle does not receives any value

Tags: visual-c++, registry

```
HKEY keyCurrentUser;
RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, &keyCurrentUser);
```

the debugger always says for `keyCurrentUser`  `CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated`. I'm using Visual c++ 2010. what am I doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Too vague.  Set a breakpoint on the actual statement.  Wait until it hits, then try again.

Comment: Same here. `RegOpenCurrentUser` returns 0, but the key is not set to a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
HKEY keyCurrentUser = 0; // !!! the difference
RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, &keyCurrentUser);
```

Now the returned key is valid! I can't think of a reason why a function checks a value it overwrites, but it seems there is one.